# Sum/ average / product in python

Tags: python, sum, average, product

I am trying to write a program which asks an input of two numbers and  then prints the sum, product and average by running it. I wrote a program but it asks an input for 2 numbers everytime i need a sum or average or product. How can I get all 3 at once, just making two inputs once.

```
sum = int(input("Please enter the first Value: ")) + \
      int(input("Please enter another number: "))
print("sum = {}".format(sum))

product = int(input("Please enter the first Value: ")) * \
          int(input("Please enter another number: "))
print ("product = {}".format(product))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variables to store the input:

```
first_number = int(input("Please enter the first Value: "))
second_number = int(input("Please enter another number: "))

sum = first_number + second_number
product = first_number * second_number
average = (first_number + second_number) / 2

print('Sum is {}'.format(sum))
print('product is {}'.format(product))
print('average is {}'.format(average))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your numbers to variables and then reuse them for the operations.

**Example**

```
x = int(input("Please enter the first Value: "))
y = int(input("Please enter another number: "))

print("sum = {}".format(x+y))
print("product = {}".format(x*y))
print("average = {}".format((x+y)/2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to get the numbers first, then do your operation on them.  Otherwise you're relying on the user to alway input the same two numbers:

```
a = int(input("Please enter the first Value: "))
b = int(input("Please enter the second Value: "))

print ("sum = {}".format(a+b))
print ("product = {}".format(a*b))
print ("average = {}".format((a*b)/2))
```